# How to install python packages on python2.7 using yum

Tags: python, pip, redhat, yum

Here is my question:

How to install python packages on python2.7 using yum, as yum by default installs packages on 2.4 (the default python on redhat).

OR

How can I install yum on python2.7 to make its default installation is python2.7

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Yum will get its packages from a set which have been 'approved' by RedHat for that particular RedHat version, and they've only 'approved' up to v2.4 for your version. You'll either have to upgrade RedHat, or use 'unapproved' packages.

Comment: If you are sure of your answer, add it as an answer blow .. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do that.

Yum will get its packages from a set which have been 'approved' by RedHat for that particular RedHat version, and they've only approved up to v2.4 for your version.

So, you'll either have to upgrade RedHat, or use 'unapproved' packages.

From experience, RedHat are somewhat slower to approve new versions of packages than some other distributions, so you might want to switch to the RedHat-esque [Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/) or the Debian-esque [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/), which tend to update to newer versions more quickly.